# Localbitcoins authenticated HTTP POST request error

Tags: excel, vba, api, authentication, winhttprequest

I'm trying to send POST request to LocalBitcoins API server but I'm only receiving errors (41 and 43) despite the GET request works perfectly even with parameters (arguments).

```
Sub initrequest()

'this is a POST request with no arguments  that results in error  
JsonResponse = PrivateLocalBTC("POST", "/api/notifications/mark_as_read/9b9c2b5a16a3/")

'this is a GET request, with "ads=.." parameter, that works
'JsonResponse = PrivateLocalBTC("GET", "/api/ad-get/", "ads=771318")

Debug.Print JsonResponse

End Sub
```

and there is the HTTP request sub:

```
Function PrivateLocalBTC(Method As String, endpoint As String, Optional params As String) As String

Dim NonceUnique As String
NonceUnique = CreateNonce(13)
TradeApiSite = "https://localbitcoins.com"
apikey = "..............."
secretkey = "............"

Message = NonceUnique & apikey & endpoint & params
apisign = ComputeHash_C("SHA256", Message, secretkey, "STRHEX")
If params <> "" Then urlparams = "?" & params
Url = TradeApiSite & endpoint & urlparams

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
objHTTP.Open Method, Url, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Apiauth-Key", apikey
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Apiauth-Nonce", NonceUnique
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Apiauth-Signature", apisign
objHTTP.Send ("")

objHTTP.waitForResponse
PrivateLocalBTC = objHTTP.ResponseText
Set objHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

I've tried many variation putting endpoint, nonce, apikey in the request body at .Send command , urlencoding, but no positive result.

ComputeHash_C, CreateNonce are separate functions. The code is inspired by the great shared work of https://github.com/krijnsent/crypto_vba !

LocalBitcoins API doc is here: https://localbitcoins.com/api-docs/

Answer (score 0):

It appears that after braking brains over an issue, one have to post the question on stackoverflow in order to have the revelation for the answer... I realized that I'm using an apikey that only can read from server so, naturally, cannot modify server data by a POST request. Creating and using the right key, with write rights, solved the issue!
The working code is:

```
Function PrivateLocalBTC(Method As String, endpoint As String, Optional params As String) As String
'Method "GET', "POST"
'params format: "argument1=value&argument2=value&...."

Dim NonceUnique As String
NonceUnique = CreateNonce(13)
TradeApiSite = "https://localbitcoins.com"
apikey = "..............."
secretkey = "............"

Message = NonceUnique & apikey & endpoint & params
apisign = ComputeHash_C("SHA256", Message, secretkey, "STRHEX")
If params <> "" Then urlparams = "?" & params
Url = TradeApiSite & endpoint & urlparams

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
objHTTP.Open Method, Url, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Apiauth-Key", apikey
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Apiauth-Nonce", NonceUnique
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Apiauth-Signature", apisign
objHTTP.Send params

objHTTP.waitForResponse
PrivateLocalBTC = objHTTP.ResponseText
Set objHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

The only modification is "objHTTP.Send params". Be sure to use the correct api keys!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed error no. 41. I modified this example [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47046641/how-to-use-pagination-at-api-localbitcoin)
to show that works, (read my NOTE: comments to understand better where is the problem)
Read my NOTE: comments.

```
<?php
function localbitcoins_query($path, array $req = Array()) { 
   $key='yourkey';
   $secret='yoursecret';      

   $array_mt = explode(' ', microtime());   
   $nonce = $array_mt[1].substr($array_mt[0], 2, 6);   

   $get = "";
   if ($req) {
      $get=http_build_query($req);
   }
   $postdata=$nonce.$key.$path.$get; // NOTE: here $postdata goes without '?' char before the parameters!

   $sign = strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha256', $postdata, $secret)); 

   $headers = array(
      'Apiauth-Signature:'.$sign,
      'Apiauth-Key:'.$key,
      'Apiauth-Nonce:'.$nonce
   );
   $ch = null;
   $ch = curl_init('https://localbitcoins.com'.$path.( $get=="" ? "" : "?".$get)); // NOTE:  here it's necesary '?' char before the parameters!
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);

   $res = curl_exec($ch);
   if ($res === false) throw new Exception('Curl error: '.curlerror($ch));
   $dec = json_decode($res, true);   
   if (!$dec) throw new Exception('Invalid data: '.$res);
   curl_close($ch);   
   return $dec;
}

$getinfo = array();
$api_endpoint = '/api/dashboard/closed/';
$array_params = array(    "order_by" => "-closed_at"
                        , "start_at" => "2019-08-14 18:00:26+00:00" 
                        );
$getinfo = localbitcoins_query($api_endpoint,$array_params);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($getinfo); echo "</pre>"; 
?>
```